# regex to get all characters between certain split-words

Tags: python, regex

My string contains `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` keywords, each of them is always upper case and pre- and suffixxed with a space.

This is my test-string:

```
X OR Y OR Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ OR A OR B AND C NOT E NOT F
```

I would like to get:

- all blocks connected with `AND` and separated by either `OR`, `NOT` or the beginning/end of the string. For my example i am looking for `Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ` as well as `B AND C`. This is what i came up with, which returns `Z AND ZY AND ZZ` instead of `Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ` because of the `\w`, but i can not up with any better idea:

```
import re

input_string = "X OR Y OR Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ OR A OR B AND C NOT E NOT F"
and_pairs = re.findall("\w AND .+?(?= OR | NOT )", input_string )
```

- also i would need all terms preceeded by a `NOT`, as well as all terms followed by an `OR` in separate lists.

I dont want to seem lazy, but regex is driving me crazy (unintended rhyme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to find the `AND` pairs:

```py
import re

input_string = "X OR Y OR Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ OR A OR B AND C NOT E NOT F"
matchRegex = r"(.*?)(?:(?: OR | NOT )(\w+))+?"

regexdata = re.findall(matchRegex, input_string)
regexdata = list(sum(regexdata,())) # flatten matches
print(regexdata)

matches = [""]
for idx, data in enumerate(regexdata): # combine separated matches
        if idx % 2 == 0: matches[-1] += data
        else: matches.append(data)
print(matches)

matches = list(filter(lambda match: "AND" in match, matches)) # 'and' pairs only
print(matches)
```

Output:

```py
['X', 'Y', '', 'Z', ' Z AND ZY AND ZZ', 'A', '', 'B', ' AND C', 'E', '', 'F']
['X', 'Y', 'Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ', 'A', 'B AND C', 'E', 'F']
['Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ', 'B AND C']
```

What this does is first it matches with the regex, then it combines the separated regex groups (index 1 and 2 should be combined, 3 and 4, and so on). Once that is complete, it filter out and outputs only the `AND` connected parts. If you don't need that last part you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick,

First we split the string on 'OR', then we split those items on "NOT' and then we flatten the list, leaving out the items that don't have 'AND'in them.

result:

```py
>>> t_string = "X OR Y OR Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ OR A OR B AND C NOT E NOT F"
>>> [item.strip() for sublist in [x.split('NOT') for x in t_string.split('OR')] for item in sublist if 'AND' in item]
['Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ', 'B AND C']
```

Answer (score 1):

try with split

```
input_string = "X OR Y OR Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ OR A OR B AND C NOT E NOT F"
split_pairs = re.split("( OR | NOT )", input_string)
and_pairs = list(filter(lambda split_pairs: "AND" in split_pairs, split_pairs))
print(and_pairs)
```

result

['Z Z AND ZY AND ZZ', 'B AND C']